# I want a elisp script executing a Python one-liner under the cursor

Tags: python, elisp

I am a biggner in Emacs. I start to use Emacs at the beginning of this month.

I want to port small Vim scripts to Emacs. Those scripts will enable us to calculate like this in Emacs too.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yDR0dTPu6M4

I tried to port a Vim script written below.

```
function! s:ExecPySf_1liner()
    let l:strAt = getline(".")
    call writefile([strAt], "temp.pysf")

    let l:strAt = system("python -u -m sfPP -fl temp.pysf")
    if @0 == 0
        let @0 = l:strAt
    else
        let @0 = l:strAt
    endif

    let @" = @0
    if match(&clipboard, "unnamed") >= 0
        let @* = @0
    endif
    echo @0
endfunction
```

But I have exhausted. I spent whole 3 days to write down following code.

```
(defun ExecPySf_1liner ()
    (let (  (strAt
             (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-at-bol) (point-at-eol))
            )
         )
    ) 
)
```

I wand to make Emacs to do following actions.

```
1 read one line under the cursor.
2 write down the one line string into temp.pysf file in current directory
3 execute "python -u -m sfPP -fl temp.pysf" in a shell.
4 display the returned calculated string in echo arear
5 and copy the string in the clipboard to enable a user to past the calculated result.
```

Please indicate me the corresponding elisp functions or codes.

Thanks in advance

## ===============================

Hi Chris. I modified your codes like below.

```
(defun __getLineOmittingComment ()
    "Get position after ';;' string. If there is no ;; then return line-beginning-posiion"
    (interactive)
    (goto-char (line-beginning-position))
    (let (( posAt (search-forward ";;" (line-end-position) t) ))
     (if (equal posAt nil) (line-beginning-position) posAt)
    )
)

(defun ExecPySf_1liner()
    "Evaluates the current line in PythonSf, then copies the result to the clipboard."
    (interactive)
    (write-region (__getLineOmittingComment) (line-end-position) "temp.pysf" nil)

    (let ((strAt
           (shell-command-to-string "python -u -m sfPP -fl temp.pysf" )
         ))
        (message strAt)
        (kill-new strAt)))
```

ExecPySf_1liner() calculates Legendre Symbol:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol as below.

```
import sympy as ts; Lgndr=lambda a,b:(lambda c=a%b:0 if ts.gcd(c,b)!=1 else 1 if any((c-k^2)%b==0 for k in range(1,b//2+2)) else -1)(); [Lgndr(3,p) for p in ts.primerange(3,100)] 
===============================
[0, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1]
```

> You should look at IPython. It comes with an Emacs mode that will do all this and more

I can understand your opinion. But you might slip over the fact that Python one-liners are functional programming and completed in one-liner. Because they don't use if then else syntax.  They must use lambda functions and don't use def functions.  Though they are not strictly referentially transparent, they are functional programming as elisp scripts are. And mathematical problem is easy to write in functional programming style like upper Legendre Symbol.

IPython can save their notes as Matlab, Mathematica and you can re-use them. But the contents of the  notes are tangled as a whole. Ordinary people write a valuable expression after many suck expressions. And the valuable expression depends on some forward expressions in many cases. And It is bother to bring together the depended expressions. So the note was left tangled.

After a year, when you want to re-use the valuable expression, you will forget details of the note and it will be difficult to re-use the valuable expression. Because you must remember the details as a whole.

But each Python one-liner is complete by itself. You can re-use them easily even after several years. You can easily merge Python one-liners, because they are functional programming.

You might be able to deal with Python one-liners more easily than Python expressions in IPython.

---

I learned many things from modifying your elisp codes. I become a elisp lover. And I might become more familiar to elisp than Vim script. Thanks a lot.

## ===============================================================================

> You should look at IPython :). It comes with an Emacs mode that will do all this and more. :) ?
>   I can understand your opinion. But I claim that TO USE Emacs AS IPython  is better than  TO USE IPython AS Emacs.

I extended Python slightly for mathematics. sfPP.py is a pre-processor and it changes a one-liner as following code. You don't need to write "print" because sfPP.py adds the print instruction.

```
' xy"' in 'abcd"xy"efg'
===============================
False

type __tempConverted.py
from __future__ import division
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
from pysf.sfFnctns import *
setDctGlobals(globals())
from pysf.customize import *
if os.path.exists('./sfCrrntIni.py'):
    from sfCrrntIni import *
rightSideValueAt__= ' xy"' in 'abcd"xy"efg'
print "==============================="
print rightSideValueAt__
putPv(rightSideValueAt__, '_dt')

'"xy"' in 'abcd"xy"efg'
===============================
True
```

(This example codes also indicate why I dare to use temporal one-liner file. Smart Chris will understand the reason.)

You can easily watch Python source codes in Emacs as below.

```
source(np.source)
In file: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\utils.py

def source(object, output=sys.stdout):
        snipped
    import inspect
    try:
        print >> output,  "In file: %s\n" % inspect.getsourcefile(object)
        print >> output,  inspect.getsource(object)
    except:
        print >> output,  "Not available for this object."

===============================
None
```

> You should look at IPython
>   I have been watching IPython youtube video:IPython in-depth by bits to write an article:"Use Vim/Emacs as IPython"

Do you agree with me to use Emacs as IPython ?

---

Last question.
I want to push accept button. But I don't know where it is. "Was ths post useful to you? Yes/No button" might be not the one.

Comment: I don't know enough about emacs or elisp to answer this question, but if your goal is to use Python scripting with a full-featured text editor, you may want to consider trying out http://www.sublimetext.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's something I whipped up:

```
(defun get-current-line ()
  (buffer-substring-no-properties (line-beginning-position)
                                  (line-end-position)))

(defun run-python-command (str)
  (shell-command-to-string
   (concat "/usr/bin/env python -u -m sfPP -c "
           (shell-quote-argument (concat "print(" str ")")))))

(defun eval-line-in-python ()
  "Evaluates the current line in python, then copies the result to the clipboard."
  (interactive)
  (let ((str (run-python-command (get-current-line))))
    (message str)
    (kill-new str)))
```

You can run it with `M-x eval-line-in-python`.

I changed it so that it doesn't use a temporary file, and instead evaluates the line directly. If you still want to write a temporary file it's a trivial change.

Comment: You should look at [IPython](http://ipython.org/). It comes with an Emacs mode that will do all this and more. :)

Comment: Hi GrandOpener and thanks your advice to sublimetext. But my goal is to port my Vim script to Emacs.

Comment: @ChrisBarrett Barrett I have this same issue. But when I run, "python -m somemodule -c 'print 1'", nothing is printed. Any idea why?

Comment: On my environment:Win7 console, the below error occured.
python -m numpy -c 'print 1'
C:\Python27\python.exe: No module named numpy.__main__; 'numpy' is a package and cannot be directly executed

In upper command, "-m numpy" is an obstruction

Do the below code. It worked as hoped.

python -c 'print 1'

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who stumbles upon this, I modified @Chris Barrett to prevent a newline from being appended by python's `print`. Also, for some reason, importing the module with `-m module` made the command return no output, so I import the module within the literal command.

```
(defun run-python-command (str)
  (shell-command-to-string
   (concat "/usr/bin/python -c "
           (shell-quote-argument (concat "from myutils import *; import sys; sys.stdout.write(" str ")")))))
```